# Why it has extra square bracket with $dim$ in $[d(v_a, v_b)]^{dim}$?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

I'm studying the paper and encounter this equation which $d(·,·)$ being described as Euclidean distance between two data points and $dim$ represents the dimensionality of the input data space.

$$BAVDens = \frac{|inside(v_a,v_b)|}{[d(v_a,v_b)]^{dim}}$$

Everything is straight forward except for the dominator part, I don't understand why it has extra square bracket with the $dim$ because $d(·,·)$ should already be calculated using all the dimensions already.

Do I miss anything? Thanks.

Comment: You should probably share the source. It will be hard for anyone to help you with this problem with so little information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a "density" should be a positive real number which is independent of the linear size of the objects and the used units of measurements. From these requirements it follows that the definition of this density should be "dimensionless".

When "inside" means some sort of volume then "inside" scales with the $n^{\rm th}$ power of the linear size. It follows that the denominator of your $BAV$-expression should also scale in this way. This is accomplished by inserting the $n^{\rm th}$ power of the distance $d(v_a,v_b)$.

PS: You should not link to a source behind a paywall. My answer now is out of the blue. I have not looked at the paper.

Comment: Update to exclude the link. So that mean the extra symbols are to make it more correct (verbose). Sorry, if I a bit confuse because I'm coming from programmer perspective. When seeing Euclidean distance function $d(⋅,⋅)$, I assume it will return a number (you need to implicitly use all the dimensions to calculate distance anyway)

Comment: @SaintTail: The number $d(v_a,v_b)$ scales linearly with the distance of $v_a$ and $v_b$, but $\bigl(d(v_a,v_b)\bigr)^n$ scales with the $n^{\rm th}$ power of this distance, as $n$-dimensional volume does.